# Touchpad stops working after suspend sometimes

Tags: drivers, suspend, touchpad, elantech, amd-ryzen

I have a Huawei Matebook D with an AMD Ryzen 2500u It runs Kubuntu 18.10 great with one exception. The touchpad will stop working after an extended suspend period whats wierd is if I close the lid for just a few minutes it doesn't affect the touch pad but longer periods always lock it up.  I can reset it by with `#modprobe -r psmouse` and `#modprobe psmouse` but would like to find a permanent fix. I tried the script in this thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2372591 but it didn't work for me.

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`  shows 2 devices with touchpad in the name:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse3 event7 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=309a Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN2203:00 04F3:309A Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN2203:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2203:00/0018:04F3:309A.0002/input/input21
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event9 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

`

Comment: Hey are you resolved this problem?